# C# - Most efficient way to iterate through multiple arrays/list

Tags: c#

I have five arrays of varying lengths and I need to iterate through all of them generating all possible combinations of the contents.  I'm currently using 5 nested for loops like so:

```
for (int a = 1; a < Array1.Length - 1; a++)
  {
    for (int b = 1; b < Array2.Length - 1; b++)
      {
        for (int c = 1; c < Array3.Length - 1; c++)
          {
            for (int d = 1; d < Array4.Length - 1; d++)
              {
                for (int e = 1; e < Array5.Length - 1; e++)
                  {
                    //do something
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Due to the size of the arrays, I end up with more than 456 million iterations.  I'm pretty new to programming in general, and C# specifically.  I'm just curious if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: Q: Why do you "need to iterate through all of them generating all possible combinations of the contents"?

Comment: Just as aside, your counters in loops should start from 0 (c# uses zero based indexes) and go up until Length (`counter < Length` not `counter < Length-1`)

Comment: Regardless how the code looks, if there are 456 million combinations to be made, there will be 456 total iterations of all the elements.

Comment: The number of permutations of the five arrays will be >456 million no matter what technique you use to generate them.  For a linq approach that handles an arbitrary number of arrays, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Comment: Is he asking about ways of making the loops faster (peephole optimizations)?

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the permutations?  There may be a better way if you give us more information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You go though that many iterations because there are that many combinations: this is called [*combinatorial explosion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion). You cannot do it more efficiently if you must go through all possible combinations.

You can code it with fewer lines of code or without hard-coding the number of arrays (five in your case) by using *recursion*. However, the number of iterations is not going to change, only the number of lines of code.

```
void processCombination(int[] combination) {
    // combination[i] has the index of array #i
    ...
}
void combine(int p, int[] indexes, int[] sizes) {
    if (p == indexes.Length) {
        processCombination(indexes);
    } else {
        for (indexes[p] = 0 ; indexes[p] != sizes[p] ; indexes[p]++) {
            combine(p+1, indexes, sizes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not _entirely_ true.  If he know's something the compiler doesn't, he could unroll some of the loops / order them to benefit caching, but the improvement will likely be minimal.

Comment: +1. Direct iteration over array (with correct ranges :)) is definitely most efficient way in C#. (Usefulness of 456M items is questionable, but it is not what was asked in the question).

Comment: Another point: in C# if you iterate over the array from 0 to array.length(as is done in the example in the question, more or less), the jitter will remove the bounds checks on the indexing, resulting in a performance improvement of about a factor of 3 over keeping the bounds checks in.

Comment: @sybkar In situations like that the limiting factor is usually the "payload" of the algorithm, not the loops themselves (with the exception of, perhaps, the Floyd-Warshall's algorithm). So I decided not to touch this topic: if the OP can optimize the number of times he must execute the innermost body, the effect is going to beat unrolling hands-down :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yup, as I said, likely minimal.  It may be more of an issue if the array's items are large, but this is all getting into micro optimization...

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  There's no way around looping through all possible combinations.  While there are certainly some duplications in the combinations, they are not a significant enough number of them to make it worthwile to seek them out.  I'll see what I can do to better optimize the calculations within the loops.