# Generate all possible combinations from multiple arrays (C#/VB.NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have **n** number of arrays and each array may contain **n** number of elements. I have to generate all possible combination of values by taking one element from each array.

I need help in C#/VB.NET language.

Below is an example.

Arr1: ( a, b, c )
Arr2: ( 1, 2 )
Arr3: ( x, y, z )

I want the combinations as (There will be 3*2*3 = 18 combinations)
a1x   a1y   a1z
a2x   a2y   a2z
b1x   b1y   b1z
b2x   b2y   b2z
c1x   c1y   c1z
c2x   c2y   c2z

if I have 4 arrays, there will be 36 combinations.
Arr1: ( a, b, c )
Arr2: ( 1, 2 )
Arr3: ( x, y, z )
Arr4: ( m, n )

Combinations:

a1xm   a1xn   a1ym   a1yn   a1zm   a1zn
…    …   …   …   …   …
…    …   …   …   …   …

Answer (score 7):

Based on article by [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

```
void Main()
{
    var set1 = new object[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    var set2 = new object[]{1,2,};
    var set3 = new object[]{'x', 'y', 'z'};

    string.Join(", ", new[] {set1, set2, set3}.CartesianProduct().Select(item => item.ToArray()).Select(item => string.Format("({0},{1},{2})", item[0], item[1], item[2]))).Dump();
}


public static class CartesianProductContainer
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
    { 
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
        return sequences.Aggregate( 
            emptyProduct, 
            (accumulator, sequence) => 
                from accseq in accumulator 
                from item in sequence 
                select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
    }
}
```

The output:

```
(a,1,x), (a,1,y), (a,1,z), (a,2,x), (a,2,y), (a,2,z), (b,1,x), (b,1,y), (b,1,z), (b,2,x), (b,2,y), (b,2,z), (c,1,x), (c,1,y), (c,1,z), (c,2,x), (c,2,y), (c,2,z)
```

Answer (score 3):

**First method**

You can use **[Nested For Loops](http://www.sourceasp.net/post36/C-sharp-Nested-for-loops.aspx)**

```
for (int i=0; i < Arr1.Length ; i++)
{  
  for (int j=0; i < Arr2.Length ; j++)
  {  
     like this..............
  }  
}
```

**Second Method**

[C# - Most efficient way to iterate through multiple arrays/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655299/c-sharp-most-efficient-way-to-iterate-through-multiple-arrays-list)

Comment: The point is you don't know how many loops you need, you are given an arbitrary number of arrays, how do you hard code a certain deep loop to accommodate that?